# Service Registration Options

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have this class which gets Authorization Header value from Header and store it into variable like this:

```
public class AuthenticationHeader
{
   private static  IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
   public AuthenticationHeader(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
   {
      _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
   }
   public string AuthHeader => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Headers["Authorization"]
}
```

And I have registered this class for DI like this in my `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddScoped<AuthenticationHeader>();
```

And then this class is used in my NetworkClient using Constructor Injection.

```
public ClubMatasClient(HttpClient client, ILogger<ClubMatasClient> logger, AuthenticationHeader authHeader)
{
   _client = client;
   client.BaseAddress = new Uri("url");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
   _logger = logger;
   AuthToken = authHeader.AuthHeader;
}
```

I have read life cycle of `Scoped` and `Transient` in here [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes) and I am confused which one should I use. I don't want to mix my Authentication Headers that are coming in my Request headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scoped is per http request, Transient is per type.

Since you Authorization Header is per request you can register `AuthenticationHeader` class as Scoped that means all types created to serve your request will get the **same** instance.

But you can also register it as Transient, then all types created to serve you request will get **new** instance of `AuthenticationHeader` that internally use IHttpContextAccessor that will give you the same HttpContext for your http request.

So you can use both, the only consideration is memory consumption. Scoped will use less memory.

**Edit:**
Actually you can also use Singleton because `IHttpContextAccessor` [registered](https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/HttpServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L27) as Singleton and [internally](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/425c196cba530b161b120a57af8f1dd513b96f67/src/Http/Http/src/HttpContextAccessor.cs#L10) it uses AsyncLocal to store current context. But I wouldn't recommend it because in future `AuthenticationHeader` can be extended with some additional logic that will break the behavior.

Comment: @Arthur actually I tried using `Singleton` but it storing the AuthToken and if I added Authorization Header with value in it, it would work fine (request executed successfully) but it worked fine even I sent empty Authorization Header which was wrong, because due to registering as Singleton it was storing the last Header value.

Comment: @Shabirjan, it's weird. I'll try to check it to find why. It should work fine due to AsyncLocal.

Comment: @Shabirjan I just checked it and everything works as expected. You might have problem in other place.

Comment: No when I registered my AuthorizationHeader as Singleton, First Request that contains Authorization header worked fine. When i tried second request at same time. I added Empty Authorization Header, by logic it shouldn;t work, but when i debug the AuthHeader had old value in it. So the request with Empty Auth Header also executed successfully.

Comment: @Shabirjan do you have the validation of header on client side before sending it or on server side? If on client, what do you do in case of lake of header? If on server, are you sure the validation is correct and empty token not permitted?

Comment: Auth token is generated by login which i am saving at mobile side and whenever i want to call a request which required Auth token i add that as header, now at my server i get that request , check if header is included than i call another server which requires that header. And than either request is executed successfully or it fails.

Comment: Very odd. I tried different scenarios and always get expected header. If I set header to some value I get this value, if header is empty I get empty string, and if I don't send Authorization header I get null. Tried it one after another in different order and always get correct value.

Comment: I also get null if i dont send AuthHeader, but when i sent Header with empty value I get the old value when i register my `AutheticationHeader` as singleton.

Comment: ok found the issue. now its working fine in Singleton as well. But still i believe i shouldn't be using singleton for this.

Comment: Just curios what was the problem?